# I am not able to upload Logs from Cloudwatch to my s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am not able to upload Logs in Cloudwatch to S3 bucket through Amazon Console. As it is showing the following error message. Can any one please help me.

"One or more of the specified parameters are invalid e.g. Time Range etc"

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are doing -- for example: Are the logs in "CloudWatch Logs" or are you referring to "CloudWatch Metrics"? What command are you using to trigger the export? Did you follow the directions on the [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using an S3 bucket with encryption. This error is shown when the export task to S3 fails due to the fact that CloudWatch Logs export task doesn't support encryption on server side yet.

(I reproduced this).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was wrong access permissions configured on the bucket policy. It works with AES-256 encryption enabled in my test run.